# Redirects to login.aspx but not to default.aspx

Tags: asp.net, web-config

So I have set up my web.config to authenticate forms. I have the two pieces of code in my web.config but it is acting strange. When you go to www.mysite.com it redirects to the login.aspx page but when you go to www.mysite.com/default.aspx it does not redirect. why is it doing this? I also have the default doc set as default.aspx

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"         defaultUrl="account/default.aspx" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>

<location path="default.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 1):

As clearly shown in the config file, you have allowed unauthenticated users to access "default.aspx" URL explicitly. There is no such thing for "/" URL. Note that it does not matter that they (might) end up pointing to the same physical file on disk eventually. Only the URL matters for authorization purposes. You can clone your `<location>` tag and simply have another one for `path="/"` that allows access to all users, regardless of their authentication status.

Comment: so are you saying add this?: <location path="/">
  <system.web>
   <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
   </authorization>
  </system.web>
 </location> .. because that doesnt work

Comment: @tytyguy There's something weird going on with your setup. Perhaps some module is doing some sort of rewriting or something. Apparently, this issue is caused by extensionless URLs IIS extension in ASP.NET 4. If you disable that, it should work. Nevertheless, it might be a good idea to put all the protected URLs in a folder and protect that instead of messing with IIS configuration/extensions.